# How can I show a string before a keyword in a data file using BASH and PERL separately?

Tags: bash, perl

My research data has variable columns. Each line has at least one label/keyword, like "PRMRYTGT" and/or "SBSDRYTGT". Below is the data example.

> 0  PRMRYTGT     16655      O     16657      H  0.991     16656      H  1.053
>
> 1  PRMRYTGT     16655      O     16657      H  1.013     16656      H  1.093
>
> 2  PRMRYTGT     16655      O     16657      H  0.931     16656      H  1.148  SBSDRYTGT     16656      H     15821      O  1.407  SBSDRYTGT     15821      O     16656      H  1.407     15823      H  1.370     15822      H  1.019
>
> 3  PRMRYTGT     16655      O     16657      H  1.052     16656      H  1.300     16113      H  1.468  SBSDRYTGT     16656      H     15821      O  1.137  SBSDRYTGT     15821      O     16656      H  1.137     15822      H  0.980
>
> 4  PRMRYTGT     16655      O     16657      H  0.881     15747      H  1.491  SBSDRYTGT     15747      H     15746      O  1.116  SBSDRYTGT     15746      O     15748      H  1.003     15747      H  1.116
> 5  PRMRYTGT     16655      O     16657      H  1.018     16113      H  1.459  SBSDRYTGT     16113      H     16112      O  1.161  SBSDRYTGT     16112      O     16114      H  1.017
>
> 6  PRMRYTGT     16655      O     16657      H  0.926     16656      H  1.369  SBSDRYTGT     16656      H     15821      O  1.103  SBSDRYTGT     15821      O     16656      H  1.103     15822      H  1.042
>
> 7  PRMRYTGT     16655      O     16657      H  0.960     16656      H  1.354  SBSDRYTGT     16656      H     15821      O  1.087  SBSDRYTGT     15821      O     16656      H  1.087     15822      H  1.060
>
> 8  PRMRYTGT     16655      O     16657      H  0.969     16656      H  1.336  SBSDRYTGT     16656      H     15821      O  1.120  SBSDRYTGT     15821      O     16656      H  1.120     15822      H  0.955
>
> 9  PRMRYTGT     16655      O     16657      H  0.951
>
> 10  PRMRYTGT     16655      O    16657      H  0.970     16113      H  1.354  SBSDRYTGT     16113      H     16112      O  1.193  SBSDRYTGT     16112      O     16114      H  0.983
>
> 11  PRMRYTGT     16655      O    16657      H  0.966     16113      H  1.204  SBSDRYTGT     16113      H     16112      O  1.317  SBSDRYTGT     16112      O     16114      H  1.053

According to research requests, I want to display the content between keywords PRMRYTGT and 1st SBSDRYTGT, and then show data after the 1ST SBSDRYTGT. The variable columns make it hard to show the data. Is there any EFFICIENT to extract the data? Again, efficient way please. My data is up to  10GB and my analysis cost up to 20 days.
I want the results look like:

> 0  PRMRYTGT     16655      O     16657      H  0.991     16656      H  1.053
>
> 1  PRMRYTGT     16655      O     16657      H  1.013     16656      H  1.093
>
> 2  PRMRYTGT     16655      O     16657      H  0.931     16656      H  1.148
>
> 3  PRMRYTGT     16655      O     16657      H  1.052     16656      H  1.300     16113      H  1.468
>
> 4  PRMRYTGT     16655      O     16657      H  0.881     15747      H  1.491  SBSDRYTGT     15747      H     15746      O  1.116
>
> ......

and

> 2 SBSDRYTGT     16656      H     15821      O  1.407  SBSDRYTGT     15821      O     16656      H  1.407     15823      H  1.370     15822      H  1.019
>
> 3 SBSDRYTGT     16656      H     15821      O  1.137  SBSDRYTGT     15821      O     16656      H  1.137     15822      H  0.980
>
> 4 SBSDRYTGT     15747      H     15746      O  1.116  SBSDRYTGT     15746      O     15748      H  1.003     15747      H  1.116

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post and add the Perl code you've already written?

Comment: A `split /SBSDRYTGT/` and a count of the items resulting might lead you in fruitful directions.

Comment: "_Again, efficient way please._" -- um ... can you _please_ show us what you've tried? This seems like a mere request for code (and efficient code "please").

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic (and too broad)

Answer (score 0):

Questions:

1. is there something wrong with your input file -- why is datapoint 5 on the same line as 4?
2. why is there SBSDRYTGT in the recommended output if you want what's "between keywords PRMRYTGT and first SBSDRYTGT"?  Your specification doesn't match your example.

This should get you started; modify to suit.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;

@ARGV == 3 or die("Usage: <infile> <outfile1> <outfile2>\n");
my ($infile, $outfile1, $outfile2) = @ARGV;

open(my $in, '<', $infile) or die($!);
open(my $out1, '>', $outfile1) or die($!);
open(my $out2, '>', $outfile2) or die($!);

while (<$in>)
{
    chomp;
    next unless $_; # skip blank lines

    /^(\d+) (.+)$/ or die("Unparseable line: $_\n"); # get datapoint num.
    my $n = $1;
    my ($p, @s) = split(/SBSDRYTGT/, $2);
    @s = map { "SBSDRYTGT $_" } @s; # add SBSDRYTGT back to elements
    print $out1 "$n $p\n\n"; # \n\n maintains doublespacing
    @s and print $out2 "$n @s\n\n";
}
```